# Steam download speed drops off a cliff and then stops

Tags: networking, kubuntu, games, steam

The basic problem: When updating a game through Steam, I get an initial spike of network activity, then the download stops.

As displayed by Steam, the speed tapers off:
[image: Steam download speed]

When looking at the actual network traffic, it spikes once, and then dies entirely:
[image: Network download speed]

Some notes here:

- Once the download is down to 0, it stays at 0. Pausing and unpausing the download has *no* effect. To restart the download, I need to restart Steam.
- Actual data is apparently received for that second, so it is not a case of total blockage. The next time I start Steam, the few MB of data I downloaded are still there. (In theory, I suppose I could get the 1GB download by restarting about 200 times...)

Now, the interesting parts: I can get a *less unstable* download by placing a severe throttle on the bandwidth.
[image: Steam download speed with throttle]
This way I can get a few hundred MB of data rather than about five MB. Nevertheless, it still eventually chokes.

I start the Steam client from a console. The output is rather verbose, but here's an example:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 15.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME has been set by the user to: /home/ernir/.local/share/Steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime
ExecCommandLine: "/home/ernir/.steam/root/ubuntu12_32/steam steam://open/driverhelperready"
ExecSteamURL: "steam://open/driverhelperready"
CAPIJobRequestUserStats - Server response failed 2
ExecSteamURL: "steam://open/downloads"
Generating new string page texture 127: 128x256, total string texture memory is 5,28 MB
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1437790054)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1437790054)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1437790054)
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1437790054)
Generating new string page texture 128: 128x256, total string texture memory is 5,41 MB
process 4301: arguments to dbus_connection_ref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2656.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
process 4301: arguments to dbus_connection_unref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2794.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
process 4301: arguments to dbus_connection_unref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2794.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
process 4301: arguments to dbus_connection_ref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2656.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
process 4301: arguments to dbus_connection_unref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2794.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
process 4301: arguments to dbus_connection_unref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2794.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
process 4301: arguments to dbus_connection_unref() were incorrect, assertion "connection->generation == _dbus_current_generation" failed in file ../../dbus/dbus-connection.c line 2794.
This is normally a bug in some application using the D-Bus library.
Generating new string page texture 129: 24x256, total string texture memory is 5,44 MB
Generating new string page texture 130: 256x256, total string texture memory is 5,70 MB
Generating new string page texture 132: 48x256, total string texture memory is 5,75 MB
```

The `CAPIJobRequestUserStats - Server response failed 2` line is the only one that looks promising, but searching for it hasn't gotten me anywhere.

Additional information:

- Steam works perfectly on the Windows partition of the same machine.
- The [DNS troubles some have mentioned](http://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/2/616189106498372437/) don't seem to be the issue - or at least, installing and restarting dnsmasq didn't do anything.

I am running Kubuntu 15.04 now, the problem was identical under Kubuntu 14.04 and 14.10. System information (as reported by Steam):

```
Processor Information:
    Vendor:  GenuineIntel
    CPU Family:  0x6
    CPU Model:  0x3a
    CPU Stepping:  0x9
    CPU Type:  0x0
    Speed:  3800 Mhz
    4 logical processors
    4 physical processors
    HyperThreading:  Unsupported
    FCMOV:  Supported
    SSE2:  Supported
    SSE3:  Supported
    SSSE3:  Supported
    SSE4a:  Unsupported
    SSE41:  Supported
    SSE42:  Supported

Network Information:
    Network Speed:  

Operating System Version:
    Ubuntu 15.04 (64 bit)
    Kernel Name:  Linux
    Kernel Version:  3.19.0-25-generic
    X Server Vendor:  The X.Org Foundation
    X Server Release:  11701000
    X Window Manager:  KWin
    Steam Runtime Version:  steam-runtime-release_2015-06-12

Video Card:
    Driver:  NVIDIA Corporation GeForce GTX 650 Ti/PCIe/SSE2

    Driver Version:  4.5.0 NVIDIA 346.59
    OpenGL Version: 4.5
    Desktop Color Depth: 24 bits per pixel
    Monitor Refresh Rate: 59 Hz
    VendorID:  0x10de
    DeviceID:  0x11c6
    Number of Monitors:  2
    Number of Logical Video Cards:  1
    Primary Display Resolution:  1680 x 1050
    Desktop Resolution: 3360 x 1050
    Primary Display Size: 18,07" x 11,65"  (21,50" diag)
                                            45,9cm x 29,6cm  (54,6cm diag)
    Primary Bus: PCI Express 16x
    Primary VRAM: 1024 MB
    Supported MSAA Modes:  2x 4x 8x 16x 

Sound card:
    Audio device: Realtek ALC887-VD

Memory:
    RAM:  16001 Mb

Miscellaneous:
    UI Language:  English
    LANG:  is_IS.UTF-8
    Microphone:  Not set
    Total Hard Disk Space Available:  104234 Mb
    Largest Free Hard Disk Block:  11192 Mb
```

Any and all insight is appreciated at this point!

Comment: Does this also happen in FireFox when downloading a large file?  Leave a comment @Fabby with the reply.

Comment: @Fabby, no,  all other network activity is as expected, including (large) Firefox and Chrome downloads, as well as Torrents. As far as I can tell, it is specific to Steam. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was a problem solved by `dnsmasq` after all.

I can't tell you why it didn't cut it earlier, but on a *fresh Ubuntu 15.10 install*, I went through the following steps:

First, installing some libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl3 libcurl3-gnutls libcurl4-openssl-dev
```

and then installing Steam. The speed displayed the same characteristics (initial spike, then nothing, as before). *However*, this time installing `dnsmasq` and restarting the service did the trick.

```
sudo apt-get install dnsmasq
sudo service dnsmasq restart
```

I consider the issue solved, although I would have preferred a solution that didn't involve a full OS reinstall.